# Android: Gcm is Getting Hanged due to Thread Notify and Wait

Tags: android, thread-safety, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

In my demo project i am using a GCM for receiving the push message. I need to process the push message i am receiving in a synchronised way.. Once i received my push i need to do some task and send the acknowledgement to my server(the ack. is sent by a Async task).My project is working fine in normal scenario's, but if i switch off my Data Connectivity and if i give 10 push message and then i switch on my Phone's Data connectivity , My GCM is getting Hanged as it receives message as a bunch and after that it is not processing my push. Plz help to solve this problem

MyGCMService.java

```
public class MyGCMService extends GCMBaseIntentService{
    .....

    public GCMIntentService() {

        ...
        myThreadClass =new MyThreadClass();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onRegistered(Context context, String registrationId) {

        ....
    }

    @Override
    protected void onUnregistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
        ....
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {

        try{
        //  System.out.println("*********** 4-3- "+String.valueOf(myThreadClass.getState()).equals("NEW"));
            if(String.valueOf(myThreadClass.getState()).equals("NEW"))
        myThreadClass.start();
        }catch(Exception e){

        }
        synchronized (myThreadClass) {
            ...
            myThreadClass.wait();
        }

    }


    @Override
    protected void onDeletedMessages(Context context, int total) {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Context context, String errorId) {
        ....
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean onRecoverableError(Context context, String errorId) {
        ....
    }


    public void OnDestroy() {

        super.onDestroy();

    }    
}
```

MyTreadClass.java

```
public class MyThreadClass extends Thread  {


    MyThreadClass myThreadClass;
    String LOG_TAG = MyThreadClass.class.getSimpleName();

    public void run() {
        synchronized (this) {

            Looper.prepare();

            performAction();

            notify();

        }

    }

    public MyThreadClass() {
        myThreadClass=this;
    }



    public void performMDMAction() {

        //Doing Some task and Sending Ack. through Async task
    }



}
```

**Once this thread Hangs my GCMBaseIntentService, the Override OnMessage() function is not called..**

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really shouldn't use low level synchronization methods such as wait and notify. They are very tricky to correctly use.
If you want to perform an asynchroneous task in an Android app, perhaps [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) would be suitable to your needs. If not, consider using the java.util.concurrent package.